# What happens in MySQL when a locked row, which multiple threads are waiting on, gets deleted?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, multithreading, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement where a request has to gain access to the top most row in the DB, read it and delete it, all in one go by locking the particular row.

The use-case here is that a URL shortening application is going to query this table to get a pre-generated URL key and delete it once done.

I am using Spring Data JPA, so I will add the following code

**URLKeyEntity.java**

```
@Entity(name = "urlKeyEntity")
@Table(name = "url_key")
@Data
public class URLKeyEntity {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private Long id;
 private String urlKey;
}
```

**URLKeyRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface URLKeyRepository extends JpaRepository<URLKeyEntity, Long> {

 @Lock(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
 @Query("SELECT u FROM urlKeyEntity u ORDER BY u.id")
 List<URLKeyEntity> fetchTopRow(Pageable p);
}
```

**URLKeyService.java**

```
@Service
public class URLKeyService {

 @Autowired
 private URLKeyRepository urlKeyRepository;

 @Transactional
 public String getUrlKey() {
  final URLKeyEntity u = urlKeyRepository.findTopRow(PageRequest.of(0,1));
  final String key = u.get(0).getUrlKey();
  urlKeyRepository.delete(u.getId());
 }
}
```

What I am having difficulty understanding is how this will play out when multiple threads are trying to execute the same method.

Say, threads **T1** and **T2** are executing the same method **parallelly**. At any given point, T1 acquires the lock on the first row R1 while T2 waits for the lock on the same row.

By the time T1 is done, the row itself does not exist, how will T2 then proceed?

And if we acquire a lock on the entire table, then that may result in poor performance as the write load increases.

What is the best way to handle this so that locking does not become a bottle-neck in scalability?

Answer (score 0):

> and delete it once done

Are you talking about milliseconds later?  Or hours later?  Locking the row "until it is done" is practical for up to a few seconds.  For longer "locks", you need to invent a different mechanism.  (We can discuss that if needed.)

This is how to InnoDB to lock the row, let you do some work, then delete it:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT id, ...
     ORDER BY ... DESC
     LIMIT 1
     FOR UPDATE;   -- 'lock' the last row
... do the work
DELETE ... WHERE id = ...;
COMMIT;
```

If you need to break out of that sequence of statements, do a `ROLLBACK`.

If you expect to have multiple threads each working on some row in that table, say so.  What I have presented essentially can only do one "last row" at a time; other threads must wait.

(If you want to discuss your code, please provide the generated SQL; it is the lingua franca of this site.)